# Где хранить ip сервера для клиента android

Tags: android

Приветствую!
Возник вопрос: в клиенте android не хочется прошивать ip сервера, давно слышал, что в google analytics есть возможность хранить некие настройки в xml в консоли разработчика, к которым можно обратиться приложением, но точнее не помню и не могу найти.
Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: А почему вы его не хотите прошивать в коде? Он может поменяться, или кто-то готов взломать ваше приложение, сменить адрес сервера и выложить свою версию?

Comment: Скорее первая причина, адрес сервера может поменяться или придется поменять хостинг по другим причинам. Кроме того, есть настройки и кроме адреса, изменение которых не стоит перевыпуска новой версии приложения, хотелось бы иметь большую гибкость.

Comment: Остальные настройки вы можете подгружать и со своего сервера. Проблема только в возможном изменении адреса сервера. Тут либо надеяться на возможности Google (насчет этого ничего сказать не могу), либо загружать адрес сервера с другого сервера. Этот вариант больше подходит для распределения нагрузки между серверами, но всё же если есть более надёжный сервер (на котором, однако, весь серверный функционал не развернуть), то можно получать адрес с него. Но тогда придётся вшивать в код адрес доп. сервера, но других вариантов я не знаю. Разве что пользователь сам будет вбивать адрес в настройках

Comment: Или я чего-то не понимаю, или почему бы просто не купить домен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы, вероятно, слышали про [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/)

Comment: Спасибо! Это то, что я искал.